Suppose $P$ is a $p$-subgroup of the $p$-solvable group $X$. Prove $O_{p'}(N_X(P)) \subseteq O_{p'}(X)$.
I want to prove the following lemma

Suppose $P$ is a $p$-subgroup of the $p$-solvable group $X$. Then $O_{p'}(N_X(P)) \subseteq O_{p'}(X)$.

$O_{p'}(X)$ means the $p'$-core of $X$. That is, $O_{p'}(X)$ is the largest normal $p'$-subgroup of $X$.
Similarly, $O_{p'}(N_X(P))$ means the largest normal $p'$-subgroup of $N_X(P)$ where $N_X(P)$ is the normalizer of $P$ in $X$.
In the proof, the author says, by Sylow's theorem, it suffices to assume $O_{p'}(X)=1$ and then show $O_{p'}(N_X(P))=1$.
Why we can assume $O_{p'}(X)=1$? How does it works?

it would be helpful if you could clarify your notation. Its not immediately clear (to me) what $O_{p'}(N_X(P))$ means, for example. If it is some kind of an orbit, what is the group action in consideration? I suggest you edit the question and define the things in use.

@nickbros123  I already edit my question. Thanks for your suggestion.

$O_{p'}(X)$ is normal, and if you mod out by it, you get the special case with $O_{p'}(X)=1$, and you can pull back to the original group for the desired conclusion,

@ArturoMagidin  What is the mean "mod out"? You mean consider the quotient group? Can you say more detail?

This lemma is the Theorem 4.33 of I. Martin Isaacs' book Finite Group Theory.

@ArturoMagidin not sure if sylow theorem is needed here, but the author suggests it. I feel like there is an argument with just the natural projection to $X/P_{p'}(X)$ and arguments with pulling back. we would conclude $O_{p'}(X/P_{p'}(X))=1$, and look at $\pi(N_X(P))=N_{X/O_{p'}(X)}(\pi(P))$.
